# Where to find string constant srStandard in Delphi 2007?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Specification of `RegisterComponents` does not indicate in which unit the constant `srStandard` (the name of the 'Standard' category in the tool palette) can be found.

Comment: I've seen `stStandard` being used in the help file for `RegisterComponents`. It seemed like it would be good practice to use the resource strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to make your **design-time** package "require" designide. Then you can use unit DsnConst, which contains the srStandard string constant. It doesn't exist as a stand-alone dcu, rather it is in the designide package. It is only intended to be used from design-time packages. It cannot be used from run-time packages because designide is not redistributable.

Comment: Thanks, I would never have figured this out on my own.